# Runing trident Timeline on parentless Component

Tags: java, swing, substance, trident

I try to play `Timeline` from `Trident` animation library on parentless component.

```
MyPanel mp = new MyPanel();
mp.startAnim(); //to interpolate property
//wait for a while
jPanel1.add(mp);
```

The property is not interpolated until the component is placed on the parent container.

Is it any possibility to force Timeline to execute 'scenario' in above described environment

Comment: Please clarify your requirements again. What do you mean by a "parentless component" for instance?

Comment: In situation described above, property will not be interpolated untill I add MyPanel to visible component e.g. JFrame, Jpanel or other container.

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to `startAnim();` on an invisible component?  See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/155831)